# Calculate $\mathbb{P}(X_1 + \dots + X_n = k)$ if $X_{i}(\omega)=2 a_{i}-1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{n}$ with $\mathbb{P}(\omega):=2^{-n}$ for any $\omega \in \Omega$ and $X_{i}: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the random variables given by $X_{i}(\omega)=2 a_{i}-1$ for $\omega=\left(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n}\right) \in \Omega$.

If the random variables $S_{0}, S_{1}, \ldots, S_{n}: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are defined by $S_{k}=X_{1}+\ldots+X_{k}$, what is $\mathbb{P}\left(S_{n}=k\right)$?

I started as follows, but I could not continue.

**My attempt:**

$\mathbb{P}(S_n=k) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 + \dots + X_n = k) = \mathbb{P}(\omega \in \Omega: \sum_{i=1}^n 2a_i -1 = k) = \cdots$

If you have any ideas on how to proceed I would be grateful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you able to see that $a_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$, then the required probability is related to the pmf of a binomial random variable